# for all - complex image array editing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm struggling with a piece of code. It should convert the values of the complex array of an image (complex, because of a previous FFT) into just the phase of the complex numbers in the same array.

The problem seems to me is that the `for...in` setting doesn't work through the array. This is what I tried :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cmath as cm
image = plt.imread('/Users/.../Mikro.png').astype(float)
#grayscale the image
image_gray = np.mean(image, -1)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(image_gray, cmap='gray',vmin=0, vmax=1)
plt.title("Original_Gray")
#FFT works fine
image_shift = np.fft.fftshift(image_gray)
image_fft = np.fft.ifftshift(np.fft.fft2(image_shift))
#Output FFT Phase: Will generate the phase shifts - here comes the problem
def plot_phase(im):
    from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
    with np.nditer(im, op_flags=['readwrite'], order='F') as it:
        for x in it:
            x = cm.phase(x)
    plt.imshow(im, norm=LogNorm(vmin=5))
    plt.colorbar
plt.figure()
plot_phase(image)
plt.title("FFT Phase Image")
```

Comment: I believe fundamentally the problem is that by reassigning to x, you are overwriting the local variable and not the object to which iterator it is pointing.

Comment: Also, you are calling the plot_phase() on original image, and not complex image_fft

Comment: ok, thanks a lot. I tried some different ways. I'm very new to python, so maybe I miss a point here. Is it possible to accomplish this, by using a return phrase, like

for x in it:
            x = cm.phase(x)
            return x

Answer (score 0):

Rather than assigning to a local variable and immediately discarding the value:

```
            x = cm.phase(x)
```

you probably want:

```
            it.operands[0][it.index] = cm.phase(x)
```

However, using `nditer()` at all seems like the Wrong Thing.
When you look at `dir(image_fft)`, are you *sure* none of those attributes
could give you the desired figures?
I think that

```
            image_fft.imag
```

would produce the phases you're looking for.